# How do you get the Node IP from inside a Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a go app that is creating prometheus metrics that are node specific metrics and I want to be able to add the node IP as a label.

Is there a way to capture the Node IP from within the Pod?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, it seems `fieldPath` is required now:

```
  env:
    - name: NODE_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Comment: This seems to be giving the internal IP, any way I can get the external Node IP?

Comment: @martinkaburu most cloud providers allow you to query the external IP using their metadata API. There are also third-party services that annotate new pods with their host IP.

Answer (score 23):

> Is there a way to capture the Node IP from within the Pod?

Yes, easily, using the [`env: valueFrom: fieldRef: status.hostIP`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#objectfieldselector-v1-core); the whole(?) list is presented in the [`envVarSource`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#envvarsource-v1-core) docs, I guess because `objectFieldSelector` can appear in multiple contexts.

so:

```
containers:
- env:
  - name: NODE_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
         status.hostIP
```

Comment: It appears that `status.hostIP` is only available in Kube 1.7+

Comment: Brilliant!! I've keep searching it for hours without an effective solution. This is exactly what I'm looking for! What a pitty I cannot give you 1 hundred votes

Comment: @frederix It's not true. Hopefully, I'm able to get the hostIp by using status.hostIP  in my cluster with version 1.15

Comment: Hi All, Do we have a field to retrieve hostName instead of hostIP?