# Kubernetes: Fetch system IP:PORT on which our pod is running

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, inet

We have a setup where a single pod is running inside a node in our machine.

In normal Java application when we use the java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), it would give the system hostAddress where the server is running. But if the same API is called in a java application running inside a Kubernetes pod it would give the hostAddress of pod. Please let me know how to get the hostAddress of the system where the kubernetes pod is running and not the pod hostAddress?

Edit: Do not want to add Kubernetes dependencies, so please suggest how to achieve it in Java without kubernetes APIs.

Comment: Why do you want to get the IP of the host where the pod is running?

Comment: @Thomas, One of our application requirement is on server start up, we assign an ID based on the server which is coming up, for this we need a mechanism in the java code to provide the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the Node IP from inside a Pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047434/how-do-you-get-the-node-ip-from-inside-a-pod)

Comment: @p10l We are looking for a solution without using kubernetes APIs. Do not want to add the dependency of the same in our project.

Comment: Sounds like your system architecture is not a good fit for kubernetes (or cloud) as a runtime. Nevertheless the answer hinted by p10i is correct, it does not introduce a kubernetes dependency, neither, just read an environment variable.