# Finding the IP on which multi instance kubernetes leader pod is running from python on a 3 cluster/VM architecture

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am working on a 3 node(VMs) architecture which have different IP all in same network, on each of these VMs some kubernetes pods are running. I want to know the IP/node on which leader instance of pod 'multi-pod' is running it has 2 instances.

I am able to get the leader using below command :

```
kubectl exec -it multi-pod --namespace=kube-system -- robotctl leader robot-orch | grep Single
```

I get the below o/p mentioning the leader :

```
| multi-pod-kf6pq | multi-pod-kf6pq | Healthy | Singleton | 00 days 10 hours 57 minutes | Leader and only available      |
```

How could I get the IP address or node on which this instance is running?
Node names are something like 'cluster-1/2/3'. Also I am trying to translate this workflow into a Python code.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047434/how-do-you-get-the-node-ip-from-inside-a-pod) answer your question?

Comment: Please make use of the [extensive search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkubernetes%5D+node+ip+from+pod) during your stay in the stack exchange network